# Add animated checkbox to Bootstrap form-check

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, css-animations

I'm really bad with CSS animations but I found this great animated checkmark on SO that I'd love to use in my code. But I don't know how to include it in.

This is my html code for checkmark, I'm using Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">checkmark</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

And here is the animated checkmark [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hybrid8287/gtb1avet/1/).

Can someone please let me know how I can include this in my HTML code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try as follows.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/38/)

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+svg {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+svg {
  display: block;
}

.check-box {
  position: relative;
}

.check-box label {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  padding-left: 88px;
}

.check-box label svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="check-box">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_1" value="item 1" />
      <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
        <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
        <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
      </svg>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="check-box">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_2" value="item 2" />
      <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
        <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
        <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
      </svg>
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </label>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! This works great! I'm just wondering if there's a way I add an empty circle when the checkbox is unchecked?